# How to convert 64 bit binary string in to a decimal number in tcl?

Tags: binary, 64-bit, tcl, decimal

I'm trying to convert a 64 bit binary string value () in to an integer but I'm apparently hitting the tcl limit and getting:

```
integer value too large to represent
```

Binary String:

```
000000000000101000000000000010100000000000000100
```

The proc I'm using to convert from binary to integer is:

```
  proc binary2decimal {bin} {
     binary scan [binary format B64 [format %064d $bin]] I dec
     return $dec
  }
```

I tried  using 64 for formatting and also tried LI to no avail. I read about "wide" but did not understand if it could be applied here.

P.S: I'm using tcl 8.4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, the error is coming from `format`, which isn't very happy with 64-bit numbers by default (for backward compatibility reasons) but we're really working with a string of characters there, so `%064s` (`s`, not `d`) is a suitable fix.

You really ought to switch to using Tcl 8.5 where this is *much* easier:

```
binary scan [binary format B64 [format "%064s" $bin]] W dec
```

Or even just:

```
set dec [expr "0b$bin"]
```

In 8.4, you've got to do more work as the 64-bit support was a lot more primitive.

```
binary scan [binary format B64 [format %064s $bin]] II d1 d2
set dec [expr {wide($d1)<<32 | wide($d2)}]
```

That's slightly non-obvious, but the `I` format is and always has been documented to work with 32-bit values only. So we stitch the two (big-endian) half-values back together after scanning.